# str_replace заменяет строку раньше, чем надо

Tags: php

В общем есть файл funtions.php

```
function template($name) {
    include $name.'.php';
}
```

Тут всё понятно. Затем идёт файл main.php

```
$main = file_get_contents('main.tpl');
$main = str_replace('{static}',template('static'),$main);
echo $main;
```

Вроде бы понятно зачем он нужен.
Дело в том, что в main.php файл static.php подключается, хотя в main.tpl нету строки {static}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из логики и документации можно предположить, что функция str_replace ожидает вторым параметром значение, а не функцию. Поэтому и происходит вызов template раньше поиска замены. Если static файл, который вы подключаете в template содержит html код - он будет вставлен как есть в поток вывода.
От того полагаю у вас сначала идет вывод static.php а затем echo $main.

Comment: Я в этом новичек, не подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы происходил поиск и только затем замена на функцию?

Comment: @НикитаЧереп Как вариант, Вам необходимо модифицировать вашу функцию template добавив перед include конструкцию `ob_start();` а после include - `return ob_get_clean();`